# rEFInd loads with blank screen (logo only, no options to boot from)

Tags: boot-loader, refind

Upon booting and choosing rEFInd, I get a blank screen as shown in [this post](https://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/bcf53133ab/).
[image: white screen with only refind logo, no boot choices]

My filesystem is like so:

```
$ mount
/dev/mapper/luks-71740d10-cf57-4b82-9311-aa584acaa81e on / type btrfs (rw,relatime,compress=lzo,ssd,space_cache,subvolid=256,subvol=/arch)
/dev/nvme1n1p2 on /boot type ext4 (rw,relatime)
/dev/nvme1n1p1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

The contents of my boot partition is (omitting refind icons directory for brevity):

```
$ ls -lR /boot/
/boot/:
total 159116
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 85725131 Nov  7 13:32 initramfs-linux-fallback.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 62696900 Nov  7 13:32 initramfs-linux.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  4769792 Jun  8 13:31 intel-ucode.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  9735104 Nov  5 13:39 vmlinuz-linux

/boot/efi:
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:38 EFI

/boot/efi/EFI:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Nov  7 14:38 refind
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 19  2021 tools

/boot/efi/EFI/refind:
total 412
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr 19  2021 drivers_x64
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root   8192 Nov  7 13:25 icons
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Apr 19  2021 keys
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   4096 Nov  7 14:38 vars
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    140 Nov  7 13:25 BOOT.CSV
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  37839 Nov  7 14:39 refind.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  34513 Nov  7 13:25 refind.conf-sample
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 317712 Nov  7 13:25 refind_x64.efi

/boot/efi/EFI/refind/drivers_x64:
total 72
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 69776 Nov  7 13:27 ext4_x64.efi
```

My configuration is as follows:

```
menuentry "arch" {
  icon      /EFI/refind/icons/os_arch.png
  volume    3c3b698a-8212-324b-9b63-4dc3a7a98aee
  loader    /vmlinuz-linux
  initrd    /initramfs-linux.img
  options   "luks.uuid=71740d10-cf57-4b82-9311-aa584acaa81e root=UUID=15773c68-a4e5-49b5-8071-f390750b7162 rootflags=compress=lzo,ssd,subvol=arch ipv6.disable_ipv6=1 add_efi_memmap rw"
}

menuentry "windows" {
  icon      /EFI/refind/icons/os_win.png
  volume    13aa9955-4538-40ac-b674-006c334b5088
  loader    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
}
```

My devices are as follow:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="Windows RE Tools" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="08C4E6C5C4E6B45A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="4eced110-9723-4dde-955c-b0ab8576869b"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: TYPE="BitLocker" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="a358833d-f07c-45f8-9119-3592577bfd23"
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="4CE7-C215" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="13aa9955-4538-40ac-b674-006c334b5088"
/dev/nvme0n1p4: BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="D2063641063626BF" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="32a62eef-7764-4de9-b230-e582a2fba9ef"
/dev/mapper/luks-71740d10-cf57-4b82-9311-aa584acaa81e: UUID="15773c68-a4e5-49b5-8071-f390750b7162" UUID_SUB="b79765d9-5a84-4327-b8e0-b4a7c27107a8" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs"
/dev/nvme1n1p2: UUID="db6871f3-f5d5-4d46-965e-7bbd9d335d34" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="3c3b698a-8212-324b-9b63-4dc3a7a98aee"
/dev/nvme1n1p3: UUID="71740d10-cf57-4b82-9311-aa584acaa81e" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="004162c0-d9e6-5043-8427-630a0efce107"
/dev/nvme1n1p1: UUID="0298-8CEA" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="82f72318-1bba-2d4b-936d-41142e979d9f"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: PARTLABEL="Microsoft reserved partition" PARTUUID="2d6499be-a167-4920-93d6-7a15a8a82ee6"
```

There are no actual errors reported, rEFInd just boots to this blanks screen and stays there indefinitely. Pressing enter (in case this is a graphical problem and behind the scenes everything is as it should be) does nothing. Using `refind-install` from a live Arch USB disc also does not fix this, creating an improper `refind_linux.conf`. I know my `refind.conf` to be correct as it has previously worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm asking this question to get the solution on a more "mainstream" and google-able result vs. the plethora of forum/reddit/mailing list incantations of this question. The [arch linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/REFInd#Blank_rEFInd_menu_screen) rEFInd article contained a troubleshooting section, but it only advised ensuring that `esp/EFI/refind/drivers` contained only the filesystem for the `/boot` partition and no other drivers.

In an email dialog with Rod Smith (author of rEFInd), he provided a custom version of rEFInd with some logging output. Here was the key finding of that exchange, which showed that rEFInd hung on scanning an NTFS volume on a separate Windows drive.

[image: rEFInd scan failure]

Rod hypothesized the potential cause as any of the following:

> - You have rEFInd's NTFS driver installed. (You indicated in an earlier
>   e-mail that you didn't, so you may want to double-check this.) If so,
>   one of the following is likely true:
> - The NTFS volume is damaged
> - There's a bug in the NTFS driver
> - There's something about the directory/file structure on this
>   partition that's triggering a bug in rEFInd
> - Your firmware includes its own NTFS driver. I've heard rumors of such
>   implementations, but I've never encountered one myself. If this is the
>   case, one of the three preceding sub-cases would also be true.
> - rEFInd has misidentified a non-NTFS partition as being NTFS. This
>   might happen because of leftover NTFS data after a partition was
>   converted from another form. This shouldn't cause a problem by
>   itself, but it's conceivable that the same hypothetical leftover
>   NTFS data is causing the driver for the filesystem the partition
>   actually holds to malfunction. In this case, backing up the
>   partition, zeroing it out, creating a fresh filesystem, and
>   restoring it should fix the problem.
> - The built-in FAT or rEFInd EFI ext4fs driver is mistaking the NTFS
>   partition as being FAT or ext4fs, respectively, and is hanging when
>   it tries to access the volume.

The solution/workaround was to add the offending `PARTUUID` values to the `dont_scan_volumes` option in `esp/EFI/refind/refind.conf`.

One may find these via the output of `blkid`, and then add them as comma-separated values. For example:

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL="SYSTEM" UUID="4CE7-C215" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="13aa9955-1234-5678-9098-006c334b5088"
/dev/nvme0n1p5: LABEL="Windows RE Tools" BLOCK_SIZE="512" UUID="08C4E6C5C4E6B45A" TYPE="ntfs" PARTLABEL="Basic data partition" PARTUUID="4eced110-0987-6543-2123-b0ab8576869b"

$ grep dont_scan_volumes /boot/efi/EFI/refind/refind.conf
dont_scan_volumes 13aa9955-1234-5678-9098-006c334b5088,4eced110-0987-6543-2123-b0ab8576869b
```

The email exchange with Rod was in 2018 and required for me to migrate from rEFInd on Win7 to Win10, either due to a change in rEFInd's scanning behavior with Win10 partitions, or perhaps related to shipped options on a corporate computer (e.g. bitlocker). I'm adding this answer now, as a Windows 10 upgrade just added a *new partition* to the existing disc and caused this issue anew.

After hours of reading through other possible causes of this, it re-dawned on me to make sure that *all* Windows `PARTUUID` values were listed in `dont_scan_volumes`, finding that when checking `refind.conf` vs. `blkid` after this upgrade, there was a new partition to add. Once added, rEFInd again showed the expected boot options from my `refind.conf` (arch and windows).